# Nestjs - How to get injectable scope type from another service

Tags: typescript, oop, dependency-injection, nestjs

Let say I create a global account service. The global account service has a register method which has the parameter of an `AccountBaseService` class. How do you check the that service injection scope type to make sure it's a global scoped service?

Answer (score -1):

Global modules#
If you have to import the same set of modules everywhere, it can get tedious. Unlike in Nest, Angularproviders are registered in the global scope. Once defined, they're available everywhere. Nest, however, encapsulates providers inside the module scope. You aren't able to use a module's providers elsewhere without first importing the encapsulating module.

When you want to provide a set of providers which should be available everywhere out-of-the-box (e.g., helpers, database connections, etc.), make the module global with the @Global() decorator.

```js
import { Module, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CatsController } from './cats.controller';
import { CatsService } from './cats.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  controllers: [CatsController],
  providers: [CatsService],
  exports: [CatsService],
})
export class CatsModule {}
```

for more information https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules

Comment: The question was how to check the injection scope type at runtime. I need the method to throw an error when it attempts to registers a request or transient scope service at runtime.

Comment: Is there a nestjs function like `isGlobal` in order to find the scope of the service?